# wsgi service with flask not loading

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I am running a wsgi script file on a 32bit apache2.4 windows10 64bit system, but it won't load. Here's my code

#wsgi script file

```py
import sys
from the_app.wsgi import application


sys.path.insert(0, "C/xampp/htdocs/wsgi scripts/the_app.wsgi")


wsgi_handler = WSGIHandler(application)

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route("*", "/{path_info:.*}", wsgi_handler)

def one(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type','text/html')])
    return [templating.load_page({'content': 'Content of page one '}, "index.html"),]

web.run_app(app)
```

#Main.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import Template
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static/images/')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    """

    :return:
    """
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.routye(/
def contact():
    """

    :return:
    """

    return render_template('contact.html') 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run( host='127.0.0.1', port='5000', debug='True')
```

Comment: Please add an error message that you get

Comment: RuntimeError: The Apache directory 'C:\\xampp\\apache24\\htdocs' does not exist.

Comment: When I uncomment the load mod_wsgi.so in http.conf apache stops running